# Remove Duplicate object in Java 8?

Tags: java-8

In my project I am getting a lot of duplicate records with Id and I need efficient and better ways of getting unique Id as Employee records. Is there any better way than what I did ?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Builder
@Data
class Employee {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String department;
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        return true;
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Employee> employees = new ArrayList<>();
        employees.add(Employee.builder().id(1L).name("John").department("IT").build());
        employees.add(Employee.builder().id(1L).name("John").department("Legal").build());
        employees.add(Employee.builder().id(2L).name("John").department("HR").build());
        employees.add(Employee.builder().id(3L).name("John").department("Advisory").build());
        employees.add(Employee.builder().id(2L).name("John").department("Advisory").build());
        
        Map<Long, Employee> collect = employees.stream()
                .distinct()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Function.identity()));
        
        System.out.println(collect);
    }
}
```

Comment: A `.distinct()` operation based on the same property as the resulting map’s key does not provided any benefit. Since this will just drop all objects with an already encountered id, just can simply use `Map<Long, Employee> collect = employees.stream() .collect(Collectors.toMap(Employee::getId, Function.identity(), (prev,next) -> prev));` to achieve the same. Then, it doesn’t matter how `Employee`’s `hashCode` and `equals` are implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't prevent your code from generating duplicated records you can try to use a Set instead of a List.
In this way you are guaranteed to not obtain duplicated values while adding new records to Set

Comment: Can you show working example?